# Best attitude when suggested edit is refused

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

My suggested edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2447525) has been refused, at 3 vs 2. The reason invoked is: "This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost."

I strongly disagree: I removed a class in the sample code that was *completely irrelevant to the question* (and I  know the question better than the reviewers, since I've spent time helping the OP with comments and an answer), hence it makes the question more concise and clearer, and I also added `int` before `main()` to remove an error in the code also irrelevant to the question. In what sense does that change the original meaning of the question? (Have the reviewers even read the question?)

So I wonder, what is the best attitude to have in this situation? I can think of:

1. Signal it to a moderator
2. Chat with the reviewers
3. Post it on Meta
4. Do nothing (bad for SO, since it prevents the question to be better)

In any case, it is very frustrating to spend time making a question better, but finally be rejected. This strongly discourages me to do so in the future, which is bad for SO. Any solution to this issue?

Comment: What you want to contribute seems ideal as an *answer* - why not post it as one?

Comment: @Pekka웃: The edits I've suggested to the question were irrelevant to the *actual question* the OP had (how to destruct an object within the object), and I did post an answer to this actual question.

Comment: Don't change code yourself. Let the OP do that. By changing code and fixing it, you pretty much render the whole question useless.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Can you develop on why it renders the whole question useless? I don't want to be rude or anything, I just genuinely don't understand how this statement can be true. I haven't fixed the issues that were *relevant to the question*. I have only fixed other issues not relevant, keeping the other errors, and posted an answer regarding these relevant errors.

Comment: @Boris Part of the problem is that it's very hard for a reviewer (who may not be proficient in the language in question) to know whether a change to the code improves the question or makes it entirely useless. As an extreme example, if the question is "why won't this compile", and you edit to fix the typo, then you're left with a nonsense question. Because of this, it's very hard to get code changes (even good ones) through the review processs.

Comment: When the question is fairly recent, it's much easier to ask the OP to make the changes themselves. For old questions, you need to make a VERY good argument for the change in your edit summary, and even then, hope that you get good reviewers that pay attention to that sort of thing. I'll repeat the advice [that was given to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185581/clarification-on-edit-rejection) not too long ago: Get 2k and you'll no longer have to worry about bad reviews.

Comment: @jcsanyi tkx for these useful comments :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would say it *is* invalid, but that's not the subject here.

What should you do? Well, I for one would love to chat about it. If I rejected something you *honestly, truly* thought was good, I would like to know about it. Maybe you learn something from me, or maybe you convince me to change my reviewing ideas.

If you aren't able to chat with anyone, or no one is accepting the idea of chatting about it, go ahead and post on meta about it. Ask something like, 'what's wrong with this edit', rather than, 'this edit should have been accepted!'

It seems like a small difference, but the difference is with the first you will be given nice advice over why it was wrong (or nice apologies!) With the second, you will get pounded into the ground with a giant E if you are wrong. It's your choice, but I would go for the first.

There is a read-only link to our discussion on Chat [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/606/room-for-undo-and-boris). Go browse to your heart's content :)

Comment: Thx for your answer and advice :) Even though is is not the subject here, what do you mean by "it *is* invalid"? Has my edit be rightfully be rejected (and then indeed I'd love to know where I'm wrong and correct my preconceived ideas of what is a good edit), or were the reviews incorrect?

Comment: @Boris Do you have a chat profile? I can make us a private room.

Comment: If useful: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/225279/boris

Comment: @Boris That's what I needed. Just a minute...

Comment: @Boris http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/606/room-for-undo-and-boris

Comment: @Boris Try it now. Some fancy access stuff.

Comment: Why not just hold the discussion here publicly so other users can benefit as well?a

Comment: @jmort It's too long and too localized for a comment thread, IMO.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe post a summary of your discussion in the answer then.  Although, Meta Stack Overflow, despite being built on the Q&A platform, is oftentimes used to hold discussions and debate in order  to determine the best way to proceed in handling community issues... In fact, it's why Meta exists... :)

Comment: @jmort OK, I'll do that.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, the best attitude in this scenario is...

## ...RAGE.

...of the "Those fools! They rejected my work - MINE! I'll show them, **I'LL SHOW THEM *ALL!***" type.

...followed by a concerted effort to garner [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). So that you can show them all.

[image: MUAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA]

(muahahahahahahaha)

Comment: +1 haha, thx for sharing your opinion :-D

Comment: @Boris Don't overlook the last part of this answer - which is actually good advice.

Comment: @jcsanyi I'm working on that part :-D I'll show them all, muahahaha!!

Comment: We should somehow take Josh's edit privileges away. Make *him* have to suggest edits. Muwhahahahaha!